# Re-ordering of messages - Artemis

Tags: jms, messaging, activemq-artemis

I have to run two instances of the same application that read messages from 'queue-1' and write them back to another queue 'queue-2'.

I need my messages inside the two queues to be ordered by specific property (sequence number) which is initially added to every message by producer. As per documentation, inside queue-1 the order of messages will be preserved as messages are sent by a single producer. But because of having multiple consumers that read, process and send the processed messages to queue-2, the order of messages inside queue-2 might be lost.

So my task is to make sure that messages are delivered to queue-2 in the same order as they were read from queue-1. I have implemented re-sequencer pattern from Apache camel to re-order messages inside queue-2. The re-sequencer works fine but results to data transfer overhead as the camel routes run locally.

Thinking about doing it in a better way, I have three questions:

1. Does artemis inherently supports re-ordering of messages inside a 
   queue using a property such as sequence number.
2. Is it possible to run the routes inside the server? If yes, can you
   give an example or give a link to the documentation?
3. Some artemis features such as divert (split) requires modifying
   broker configuration (broker.xml file), is there a way to do them
   programmatically and dynamically so I can decide when to start
   diverting message? I know this can be accomplished by using camel,
   but I want everything to be running in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does artemis inherently supports re-ordering of messages inside a queue using a property such as sequence number.

No. Camel is really the best solution here in my opinion.

> Is it possible to run the routes inside the server? If yes, can you give an example or give a link to the documentation?

You should be able to do the same kind of thing in Artemis as in ActiveMQ 5.x using a web application with a Camel context.  The 5.x doc is [here](http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-on-using-camel-in-a-web-application.html).

> Some artemis features such as divert (split) requires modifying broker configuration (broker.xml file), is there a way to do them programatically and dynamically so I can decide when to start diverting message?

You can use the Artemis management methods to create, modify, and delete diverts programmatically (or administratively) at runtime.  However, these modifications will be volatile (i.e. they won't survive a broker restart).